# elasticsearch - snapshot creation failed due to RepositoryMissingException

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a snapshot in s3 bucket. After running request to create the new snapshot, i'm checking the status of the new snapshot and i see that snapshot state is PARTIAL, due to RepositoryMissingException.

Why is that happening ?

More information:
snapshot configuration:

```
$ curl localhost:9200/_cat/repositories
s3_repository s3
```

creation of new snapshot:

```
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_snapshot/s3_repository/snap10
{"accepted":true}
```

get details about created snapshot (here we can see the failure):

```
$ curl localhost:9200/_snapshot/s3_repository/snap10?pretty
{
  "snapshots" : [ {
    "snapshot" : "snap10",
    "version_id" : 2040699,
    "version" : "2.4.6",
    "indices" : [ "twitter" ],
    "state" : "PARTIAL",
    "start_time" : "2018-09-27T08:24:13.431Z",
    "start_time_in_millis" : 1538036653431,
    "end_time" : "2018-09-27T08:24:13.823Z",
    "end_time_in_millis" : 1538036653823,
    "duration_in_millis" : 392,
    "failures" : [ {
      "index" : "twitter",
      "shard_id" : 1,
      "reason" : "RepositoryMissingException[[s3_repository] missing]",
      "node_id" : "0yJw77XwSX62rUnhDAAclw",
      "status" : "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"
    }, {
      "index" : "twitter",
      "shard_id" : 0,
      "reason" : "RepositoryMissingException[[s3_repository] missing]",
      "node_id" : "WEzVGyjXSLWuzfD_w-sBlA",
      "status" : "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"
    } ],
    "shards" : {
      "total" : 2,
      "failed" : 2,
      "successful" : 0
    }
  } ]
}
```

Can you please assist with the issue ? why the error says that RepositoryMissingException?

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

In the end the issue was that cloud-aws plugin was installed only on master node. Once I installed the plugin on the data nodes - it worked.